# Remove grouping from grouped records

Tags: sql

I have a records on a table the is grouped as show below:

| name | count |
| --- | --- |
| Lanre | 2 |
| Jane | 1 |
| Wale | 6 |

can you anyone assist with a tsql query to "ungroup" the records such that a name appears the number of times based on the count as show below:

| name |
| --- |
| Lanre |
| Lanre |
| Jane |
| Wale |
| Wale |
| Wale |
| Wale |
| Wale |
| Wale |

Comment: **tsql** tag means you use MS SQL Server. Is that correct? Because, another tag - **plsql** - means that you use Oracle. So, which one is it?

Comment: `JOIN` to a Tally.

Comment: @Littlefoot I indicated tsql in the question but you can use *tsql* or *plsql* to answer the question, whichever you are comfortable with. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a recursive CTE to unfold them

**T-Sql (MS Sql Server)**

```
;with RCTE as (
    select name, 1 as lvl, [count] as cnt
    from yourtable
    
    union all

    select name, lvl+1, cnt
    from RCTE
    where lvl < cnt
)
select name
from RCTE;
```

**Postgresql, SQLite**

```
with RECURSIVE RCTE as (
    select name, 1 as lvl, "count" as cnt
    from yourtable
    
    union all

    select name, lvl+1, cnt
    from RCTE
    where lvl < cnt
)
select name
from RCTE;
```

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=20c3da7ce7fa8bfe63e1c3c77631cc55)*

**Pl/Sql (Oracle)**

```
with RCTE (name, lvl, cnt) as (
    select name, 1 as lvl, "count" as cnt
    from yourtable
    
    union all

    select name, lvl+1, cnt
    from RCTE
    where lvl < cnt
)
select name
from RCTE;
```

**MySql 8, MariaDB 10.3**

```
with RECURSIVE RCTE as (
    select name, 1 as lvl, `count` as cnt
    from yourtable
    
    union all

    select name, lvl+1, cnt
    from RCTE
    where lvl < cnt
)
select name
from RCTE;
```

Comment: Thanks @LukStorms for the answer, I really appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

As of Oracle, you could use query that begins at line #6 (because lines #1 - 5 represent sample data).

```
SQL> with test (name, cnt) as
  2    (select 'Lanre', 2 from dual union all
  3     select 'Jane' , 1 from dual union all
  4     select 'Wale' , 6 from dual
  5    )
  6  select name
  7  from test cross join table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
  8                                           connect by level <= cnt
  9                                          ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 10  order by name;

NAME
-----
Jane
Lanre
Lanre
Wale
Wale
Wale
Wale
Wale
Wale

9 rows selected.

SQL>
```